# Java SQL 1 million rows

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I must add 1.000.000 rows in mySQL with Java, but the process is quite long․ I have this code:

```
for(int number=45000000;number<46000000;number++){

query="insert into free(number) values ("+"'"+number+"');";
try {
    stmt.executeUpdate(query);
    System.out.println(number +" added");
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

How to accelerate the process? (40 min = 100.000 rows) Any ideas?

Comment: You could try putting the update into a transaction. Also, you should probably use a prepared statement instead of a raw string; otherwise you open yourself to SQL injection. (Plus it might be faster too)

Comment: You are doing a million queries. Can you not collect everything into a huge query and just do one query?

Comment: I'll try the all possible options, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) and batching. Something like,

```
String query = "insert into free(number) values (?)";
PreparedStatement ps = null;
try {
    ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    for (int number = 45000000; number < 46000000; number++) {
        ps.setInt(1, number);
        ps.addBatch();
        if ((number + 1) % 100 == 0) { // <-- this will add 100 rows at a time.
            ps.executeBatch();
        }
    }
    ps.executeBatch();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (ps != null) {
        try {
            ps.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it better to execute 1.000 batches or 100.000 per time and why?

Comment: @GoXr3Plus That depends on too many factors to answer simply; but there are (generally) diminishing returns to larger batch sizes.

Comment: Can you provide an article or something specific for situation like the original question?Thanks for helping.

Comment: MySQL Reference Manual: [8.2.2.1 Speed of `INSERT` Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-speed.html)

Comment: Nice.I asked you cause i insert 100.000 batches and then execute bacth in a local app.So it is better to add 1000 batches and executeBatch every time like your answer?